# Cannot install Python 2.7.8 on Windows 8

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, installation

I'm running Windows 8 (64-bit) and trying to install Python 2.7.8, but the installer never completes. It always jumps to a screen telling me the install did not complete immediately after clicking "Next" from the "Customize Python" screen. The exact text is:

"Python 2.7.8 Installer ended prematurely

Python 2.7.8 setup ended prematurely because of an error. Your system has not been modified. To install this program at a later time, please run the installer again.

Click the Finish button the exit the installer."

No error message is displayed other than this screen. I've tried running the installer through the command line, this is the log I get: http://pastebin.com/5yKcqYUb

EDIT:

I've run the installer as an administrator, still gives me the same results.

EDIT 2:

I've tried installing the 64-bit version, no change.

Comment: According to your log it's using `SysWOW64` as the `DLLDIR`, I think it's supposed to be `system32` since that is where the 64bit binaries are for 64bit machines. I'm not sure if that is your problem, but I would start there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to Windows 8.1 allowed me to install Python 2.7.8. Not sure if the problem was caused by Windows 8 or if the setup process for 8.1 corrected an issue with Windows, but the installers for both Python 2 and 3 complete successfully.

EDIT:

After a few days the issue reappeared in Windows 8.1. After exhausting the rest of my options, I remembered that I'm using Windows 8 and that the .NET framework needed to be repaired. Sure enough, it worked.

If you, too, are having this issue, try removing and reinstalling the .NET framework:

1. Go to Control Panel -> Programs & Features -> Turn Windows features on or off (on the sidebar)
2. Uncheck .NET Framework 3.5 and hit OK
3. Wait for the process to finish and restart your computer
4. Go back to Turn Windows features on or off and check .NET Framework 3.5 again. You shouldn't need a reboot this time.

Comment: The .NET steps here solved my problems for installing Python 2.7.9 on Win2k8r2 x64 also!

Answer (score 1):

Your log indicates that your system does not give regular users eleveated rights for installation.  This means that if any part of the install process needs to access secure directories, such as System and System32, it will fail unless you are running as administrator.

the log also has numerous references to MSI code 2262 - stream does not exit.  This is usually an indicator of insufficent priveledges.

So, the two steps I would recommend are:
1. Make sure you are in the davidr account so you have fuil access to the Downloads folder
2. Right-click the .MSI file and run it as administrator.

EDIT - 
Looking at your log further, I notice you are running Python2.7.8.msi.  That is the 32-bit version.  Since you are running 64-bit Windows *, I recommend installing the 64-bit version of Python 2.7.8
the MSI can be found [here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.8/python-2.7.8.amd64.msi)

Comment: Logged in as the davidr account, tried running the installer as an administrator. No luck, still getting the same result.

Comment: Tried again with the 64-bit version, still running as administrator. Still gives the same result.

Comment: okay, this is just desperation now.  Try moving the MSI into a directory your account has comeplete control of, like your Documents folder. By all accounts Windows 8 and Python 2.7 get along just fine.

Comment: Still nothing. Same with Python 3.4.2, both 32-bit and 64-bit versions. Maybe I'm cursed? Tried from Documents, Desktop, a folder in Documents, and from C: just to try.

Comment: Install Debian Linux...  seriously though, this has got to be a windows-based error. but aside from the 2262 "stream does not exist" error, there's nothing else in the log that I can see.

Comment: one other thing: is Drive C: encrypted?  the installation error 1603 at the bottom of the log is associated with file permissoins.  Either the SYSTEM account doesn't have full permissions, or you are attempting to install to an encrypted drive or Folder.

Comment: The drive is not encrypted. Attempting to install to or from another drive also does not work.

Comment: you might try looking at a new log.  the first log shows that user "Melissa" was trying to do the install.  Is "Melissa" an administrator account? or is davidr?

Comment: She is not an administrator, but she is also not logged in. I don't know why it would be trying to install as her.

Comment: Did you swap users before logging in? If you did a user swap, instead of actually logging out the first account and login with the second, it would still consider melissa to be the dominant user

Answer (score 1):

Same error on windows7 with Python 2.7.13 msi (2017-05),  installing as admin. Solution: install an older well tested python27 in c:\python27 and then run these  msi to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of struggling, I found out that AD Group Policies somehow prevented from installing with the error "..ended prematurely", even without starting copying files. Not sure which group policy it was, but i finally got python on my Windows 10. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: More info please - what did you do?

Comment: Is you PC in domain? If yes, then try to exclude it from group policy as well as the user. Also, I think, one of the reason was that I got corrupted Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

If you're upgrading a previous installation, make sure you are installing the same architecture (i.e., 64-bit vs. 32-bit).

I mistakenly tried to install a 32-bit Python over a 64-bit installation and got the same error.  Getting the proper architecture (64-bit) fixed the problem.

<sub><sup>(I realize this question is 3 years old.  This is for others who may end up here.)</sup></sub>